# NSURLConnection make a Synchronous request in backgorund

Tags: objective-c

Like the title my question is if is it possible to make Synchronous request in background.
My actual code is:

```
NSData  *dataReply = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];
```

Comment: Look at NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:toTarget:withObject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not only possible, it is actually the recommended way, the best is to call it on its own thread. On the other hand, asynchronous call is still better.